# Run shell script when saving a file in Sublime Text 3

Tags: linux, shell, sublimetext3

I'm just curious, is it possible to run shell script automatically when I hit CTRL+S in Sublime Text 3 on Linux.
It may be useful for generating CSS when modifying SASS, for example.

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out [SublimeOnSaveBuild](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeOnSaveBuild). All you need to do is set up a build system like [SASS Build](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SASS%20Build), [LESS-build](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LESS-build), [Nodejs](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Nodejs), etc., or your own custom build system, so that it's working without intervention when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>. Then, enter the particulars into SublimeOnSaveBuild's config file (which allows you to filter by file extension, so you only trigger it when saving `.sass` files, for example) and you're all set - the build will trigger each time you save a file with the specified extension.

To set up the config file, first open **`Preferences → Package Settings → SublimeOnSaveBuild → Settings - Default`**, and copy the entire contents. Close the file, and paste the contents into **`Preferences → Package Settings → SublimeOnSaveBuild → Settings - User`**, customizing anything you wish. Save the file, and things should proceed automagically from there. Setting `"build_on_save": 0` will disable the plugin.