# Run TypeScript file on Sublime text

Tags: typescript, sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I want to build a TypeScript file (with extension .ts) in the sublime text 3 console and show the output in the console the same way sublime does with `python`. How can I do that knowing that TypeScript is a compiled language? A compiled language means that it compiles the (.ts) file and convert it to Javascript (.js) file first before executing the JavaScript file.

I have tried installing the TypeScript plugin from the sublime package installer, but it needs a certain architecture to run the file as explained [here](https://cmatskas.com/getting-started-with-typescript-and-sublime-text/). Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20802285/run-shell-script-when-saving-a-file-in-sublime-text-3) question wasn't helpful as it shows how to build after saving and it didn't say anything about running a standalone file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this answer, I'm assuming that you already have installed Node.js and typescript on your local machine. If not, you can install Node.js from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and after that, you can run the following command to install `typescript` and `ts-node` using node package manager:

```
npm install -g typescript
npm install -g ts-node
```

Now, you are ready to follow these steps:

- Open the typescript file -that you need to run- on sublime text 3.
- Click on `Tools` tab, then `Build System`, then `New Build System`.
  [image]
- A new file will open.. override its content with the following JSON object. The `cmd` parameter uses `ts-node` based on the suggestion of @idleberg. And @OdatNurd suggested adding "selector": "source.ts" to make the build automatically selected for TypeScript files so you don't have to manually select it.

```
{
    "shell": true,
    "cmd": ["ts-node", "$file"],
    "selector": "source.js"
}
```

- Save the file with the name `ts.sublime-build`.
- Finally, build the script using `ts` as shown below if it wasn't automatically selected.

[image]

- Now, click <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to run the script. And you should see the output on the sublime text console.

Comment: It might be simpler to use [`ts-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node), as it allows running a TypeScript directly: `ts-node script.ts`

Comment: You can also add `"selector":  "source.ts"` to make the build automatically selected for TypeScript files so you don't have to manually select it.

Answer (score 2):

Open package control -> type or select "**Install Package**" -> type or select "**TypeScript**" -> press enter

Ex -> for mac os:  ***command+shift+p*** to open package control after that type or choose "**Install Package**", it will give list of packages to choose, type "**TypeScript**" and press enter.